# PostgreSQL simple query

Tags: sql, postgresql

My problem is to write a query (PostgreSQL) to get a 'propno' where 'newsname' is not equal 'NYT' (the answer is 40).

```
       newsname       | propno | dateadvert | cost 
----------------------+--------+------------+------
 NYT                  |     30 | 2018-01-01 | 10.2
 NYT                  |     30 | 2018-01-10 | 15.2
 NYT                  |     10 | 2018-01-02 | 20.2
 NYT                  |     20 | 2018-02-01 | 10.2
 Guardian             |     40 | 2018-02-10 |  100
 Guardian             |     10 | 2018-01-02 | 13.2
 Guardian             |     30 | 2018-01-10 | 10.8
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Do you want the maximum *propno*? Otherwise the result was 40, 10 *and* 30.

Comment: Why did you put in sqlite and mariadb tags if this is for postgres?

Comment: Nah, you see that NYT already has 10 and 30. I need to query which would print 40 because the 'NYT' does not have 40.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation and `having`:

```
select propno
from t
group by propno
having count(*) filter (where newsname = 'NYT') = 0;
```

If you have a separate table with one row per `propno`, then I would recommend `not exists`:

```
select p.propno
from props p
where not exists (select 1
                  from t
                  where t.propno = p.propno and
                        t.newname = 'NYT'
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use exists:

```
select propno
from props p
where not exists (
  select 1
  from props t
  where t.propno = p.propno
  and t.newname = 'NYT'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`HAVING` could be used to filter out `'NYT'`:

```
SELECT propno
FROM tab_name
GROUP BY propno
HAVING SUM(newsname='NYT')=0;
```